# Irregular scaling of axis in R

Tags: r, plot, scale

I have computed values for several categories for three networks. I'd like to create a bar plot in R to show the differences between these parameters for the networks. So far I plotted this with the *barplot* R function with the categories on the x-axis, their values on the y-axis and to each category three bars (one for each network).

But now I have one value which is much higher than all the others. Therefore the differences for the rest cannot be seen since they're represented only by a thin line because of that one large bar which almost fills the whole plot.

My idea was now to plot the values on the y-axis on an irregular scale, meaning for example, that one half represents the values from 0 to 300, and the other half from 300 to 3000. Is there any way to do this? Or a good alternative approach to handle this problem? I also thought of plotting the logarithm but unfortunatly I have also negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that an irregular scale isn't a good plan - I think it confuses viewers of the chart. Instead, you could use the `layout()` function to plot three separate barplots in a horizontal layout. Thus, each category could have it's own plot, with it's own scale.

If, however, you still have a single bar at 3000, while everything else is at 300, that won't really help. In that case, you could manually set your y-axis limits with `ylim=c(min,max)`. To keep the bar from stretching off the screen, you can just use simple logic to define anything > 300 as 300, or something similar. Then, put a text point there stating the actual value (using `text`, maybe with `arrow`).

With those ideas out there, I would suggest that a graph where one value is 10x the other values might not really be worth presenting, or if it is, the main takeaway from it isn't going to be "how do values 2 and 3 compare to each other", it's going to be "holy moley look how much bigger 1 is than 2 and 3". So, it might not be a big deal if one bar is giant and two are small, as long as you aren't doing all 9 on a single plot (which would screw up other, relevant comparisons). So, if you split them using `layout()`, then it wouldn't be as big of a deal.

Comment: Splitting the plot such that each category has its own scale seems a pretty obvious solution, but still I haven't thought of that. I guess it's the best way to prevent confusing the viewers. I'll try the _layout()_ function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. If this answer helps, could you go back and accept it for me so I get the reputation bonus?